# Is there a way to set the bounds and Zoom level in AGM Map?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

I am using [AGM maps](https://angular-maps.com/) for my angular 4 application, there I am facing issues, I will be having the multiple markers which are fetched from api as an array of Latitude and Longitude. I want to set the zoom level exactly covering all the markers on the map. Even if one marker in one country and other in some other country also, It should set the zoom level on load to show all the markers on the map.
 Is there a way to do that in AGM angular maps? Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Objectives

We would like to set a zoom level of AGM map to show all the markers on the map. Typically in Google Maps JavaScript API you use the `fitBounds()` method of the google.maps.Map class to achieve this.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/map

So, we have to get instance of the map object (the JavaScript API instance) and apply `fitBounds()` on it.

### Solution

I have created a simple example that has a mock service that provides JSON data for 5 markers and draws map and markers using AGM map. In this example I used @ViewChild decorator to get the instance of AGM map and listen the `mapReady` event to get instance of map object (from JavaScript API). Once I get map instance I can easily create [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#LatLngBounds) object and call `fitBounds()` on map object. Have a look at the `ngAfterViewInit()` method in the app.component.ts to get an idea.

### Code snippet

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyMarker } from './marker';
import { MarkersService } from './markers.service';
import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper, AgmMap, LatLngBounds, LatLngBoundsLiteral} from '@agm/core';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  title = 'AGM project (so48865595)';
  lat = 41.399115;
  lng = 2.160962;
  markers: MyMarker[];

  @ViewChild('AgmMap') agmMap: AgmMap;

  constructor(private markersService: MarkersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMarkers();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.agmMap);
    this.agmMap.mapReady.subscribe(map => {
      const bounds: LatLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (const mm of this.markers) {
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(mm.lat, mm.lng));
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }

  getMarkers(): void {
    this.markers = this.markersService.getMarkers();
  }

  mapIdle() {
    console.log('idle');
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>

<!-- this creates a google map on the page with the given lat/lng from -->
<!-- the component as the initial center of the map: -->
<agm-map #AgmMap [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" (idle)="mapIdle()">
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let p of markers" [latitude]="p.lat" [longitude]="p.lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

### Conclusion

If you would like to check complete example please download the sample project:

https://github.com/xomena-so/so48865595

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi.. I am loading the data from the server so it takes some time to come. I would like to setBounds only when the data from the server is received. Could you please help

Comment: You imported `LatLngBounds` from @agm/core but the types don't quite match up. Using types from @types/googlemaps fixed my error: `const bounds: google.maps.LatLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();`

Comment: another simpler solution to the `LatLngBounds` `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature` typescript error is to just add `// @ts-ignore` to the line above `map.fitBounds(bounds)`.  Also, I wish I could vote up this answer twice! XD

Comment: also, you need to add `(mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"` to your `<agm-map>` html then throw the `fitBounds` stuff into your `onMapReady(map: AgmMap)` function, since `agmMap.mapReady.subscribe` doesn't work anymore

Comment: I used this implementation and in some instances, this.agmMap is undefined. Any idea how it happens?

Comment: I figured out that I have to access the map as window['google'].maps

Comment: @RenilBabu did you find a way to initialize this after the data has been received from the server?

Comment: @xomena any suggestion for this (question)[https://stackoverflow.com/q/62386201/9380480]

Comment: Tried that. But fitBounds is ignored - all the time I see a whole piece of map. Could it be related to disabled Billing on the Google Cloud Project?

Answer (score 44):

Since September 2018 there is the [`AgmFitBounds`](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmfitbounds) directive. Super easy.

```
<agm-map
  style="width:100vw; height:100vh;"
  [fitBounds]="true">

  <agm-marker
    *ngFor="let location of locations"
    [latitude]="location.latitude"
    [longitude]="location.longitude"
    [agmFitBounds]="true"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: For this you need to upgrade your rxjs to version 6:
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If I put this code the map always stays zoomed in. It doesn't get changed according to the data. Is there anyway you can help me?

Comment: @KrushnaJoshi Best you make a new question and show us the code you have so far.

Comment: @PapaMufflon no problem figured out a way to do it. I worked it out by initializing the map all over again when data gets changed.

Comment: github guide: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/master/docs/content/guides/implement-auto-fit-bounds.md

Comment: omg should have read your answer before LOL, works like a charm

Comment: Dose exist something similar for polygons ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/agm-polygon-tujfxa?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

@renil-babu

Instead of doing the `fitBounds` on `mapReady`, you have to do it in your adding markers subscription block

```
      const bounds: LatLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (const mm of this.markers) {
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(mm.lat, mm.lng));
      }
      // @ts-ignore
      this.agmMap._mapsWrapper.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: @Papa Mufflon hi it is giving me some error No provider for FitBoundsAccessor ("S" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">

Answer (score 1):

**Objectives**
As we know AGM map allows `fitbound` to the marker, not the zone.
Based on the accepted answer above I tried using `this.agmMap.mapReady.subscribe` But in the latest version we don't have the subscribe or the `fitbound` function in the `AgmMap` object.

**Sollution**
I found an easy way to make `fitbound` available to the zone by adding markers to the zone borders.
i.e, We know a zone is a combination of `coordinates` so take the first and 3 middle coordinates of any zone and add them as hidden markers, That's all !!.

Check the below code snippet on how I did. It's a working tested code.

**Code snippet**

```html
<agm-map [zoom]="map_zoom" [fitBounds]="fit_bound" [disableDoubleClickZoom]="true" [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">

  <span *ngFor="let mapData of list_map_geojsons">
     <agm-marker [iconUrl]="marker_icon" [latitude]="mapData.lat" [longitude]="mapData.lng" [agmFitBounds]="true"></agm-marker>
     <agm-data-layer  [geoJson]="mapData.geojson" [style]="mapData.colors"></agm-data-layer>
     <!--this is our magic code to make fitbound for zones -->
     <span *ngFor="let geoMarkers of mapData.geo_makrkers">
        <agm-marker [visible]="false" [latitude]="geoMarkers[1]" [longitude]="geoMarkers[0]" [agmFitBounds]="true"></agm-marker>
     </span>
     <!--magic code ends-->
  </span>


</agm-map>
```

```js
import { AgmMap} from '@agm/core';

// My geojson
const parsed_json = JSON.parse(result.geojson);

/* ----------- This  code is wriitern for making fitbound to the zone,
 Keeping in mind that first and last co ordinates are same Here we take 
start mid, mid2 and mid3 of the zone coordinates and put it in the map 
as hidden markers so that fitbound will be available for the zone ------ */

let len = parsed_json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0].length - 1;
let mid = Math.round(len / 2);
let mid2 = Math.round(mid / 2);
let mid3 = mid + mid2;
let geo_makrkers = [
  parsed_json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0],
  parsed_json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][mid],
  parsed_json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][mid2],
  parsed_json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][mid3]
]
/* ---- End of zone fitbound -----*/

const map_data = {
  geojson: parsed_json,
  lat: latitude,
  lng: longitude,
  colors: map_colors,
  geo_makrkers: geo_makrkers
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the `LatLngBounds()` function. Here is the snippet.

```
import {AgmInfoWindow, MapsAPILoader} from '@agm/core';

latlngBounds: any;

// fits the map to the bounds
    if (this.points.length.) {
      this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
          this.latlngBounds = new window['google'].maps.LatLngBounds();
          _.each(this.points, location => {
            this.latlngBounds.extend(new window['google'].maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng));
          });
        }
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use agm-marker for some reason (you use html markers, as me) Then it is possible that your component is not supporting agmFitBounds accessor. In order to make it work write your custom component which implements FitBoundsAccessor:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, forwardRef, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FitBoundsAccessor, FitBoundsDetails } from '@agm/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'guide-map-bounds',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
    providers: [{ provide: FitBoundsAccessor, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MapBoundsComponent) }],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MapBoundsComponent implements FitBoundsAccessor, OnChanges {
    @Input() latitude: number;
    @Input() longitude: number;

    private fitBoundsDetails$ = new BehaviorSubject<FitBoundsDetails>(null);

    constructor() { }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        const latLng: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = { lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude };

        this.fitBoundsDetails$.next({ latLng });
    }

    getFitBoundsDetails$(): Observable<FitBoundsDetails> {
        return this.fitBoundsDetails$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Then in your html, inside `agm-map`

```
<guide-map-bounds [agmFitBounds]="true" *ngFor="let marker of markers" [latitude]="marker.lat" [longitude]="marker.lon">
  <agm-html-overlay [latitude]="marker.lat" [longitude]="marker.lon">
    <div class="marker" >
      
    </div>
  </agm-html-overlay>
</guide-map-bounds>
```

Please notice agm-html-overlay is custom component that doesn't support agmFitBounds

Answer (score 0):

```
    <agm-map #agmap   
      [zoom]="zoom"
      [disableDefaultUI]="false"
      [zoomControl]="false"
      [fitBounds]="true">
        <agm-marker [agmFitBounds]="true" [latitude]="curretAddLat" [longitude]="curretAddLng"></agm-marker>
      </agm-map>
***Above code will help you with AGM MAP.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).