# AGM Map: set the zoom level to include all markers

Tags: google-maps, angular-google-maps

To set the map zoom level to include all the location markers, I have tried two options as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865595/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-bounds-and-zoom-level-in-agm-map).

Here's what I did:

```
export class LocationSelectionComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

@ViewChild('AgmMap') agmMap: AgmMap;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.agmMap);
  this.agmMap.mapReady.subscribe(map => {
  const bounds: LatLngBounds = new window['google'].maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (const mm of this.mapMarkers) {
    if (mm.latitude !== this.currentLocationLatitude && mm.longitude !== this.currentLocationLongitude) {
      bounds.extend(new window['google'].maps.LatLng(mm.latitude, mm.longitude));
     }
   }

   map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
 }
}
```

Note that this.mapMarkers is an array which contains the coordinates for the map markers. These are populated in `ngOnInit()`.

As mentioned in the comment of the above post, I've also tried the following:

```
onMapReady(map: AgmMap) {
 const bounds: LatLngBounds = new window['google'].maps.LatLngBounds();
 for (const mm of this.mapMarkers) {
   if (mm.latitude !== this.currentLocationLatitude && mm.longitude !== this.currentLocationLongitude) {
     bounds.extend(new window['google'].maps.LatLng(mm.latitude, mm.longitude));
   }
 }

 // @ts-ignore
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

then in HTML:

```
  <agm-map #AgmMap [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"
                   [fullscreenControl]="true" [mapTypeControl]="true" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
            <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of mapMarkers; let i = index"
                        [latitude]="m.latitude"
                        [longitude]="m.longitude"
                        [title]="m.title"
                        [iconUrl]="m.iconUrl"
                        [animation]="m.animation"
                        (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label)">
            </agm-marker>
          </agm-map>
```

But in both instances, I don't get the map zoomed out as I expect. The reason is, when I debug the code, the mapMarkers array is empty in both instances. How do I fix this?

Comment: I just figured out, it's much more easier. You don't have to do it manually, all you have to do is to add [fitBounds]="true" to the <agm-map> and  [agmFitBounds]="true" to the <agm-marker>

Answer (score 15):

Add `[fitBounds]="true"` to `<agm-map>`
Add `[agmFitBounds]="true"` to `<agm-marker>`

Remove `[usePanning]="true"` from `<agm-map>`

For more usability Add clustering: 
[install this module and follow the instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agm/js-marker-clusterer)

Comment: Why do you have to remove Pannig? What if i want to use them together?

Comment: It automatically pans the map like a charm. There's no need to add it explicitly.

Comment: Is it possible to fit all not markers but polygons to view?